# Error in if (type == "package") package <- topic : argument is of length zero

Tags: package, simulation

I am doing a simulation in Studio and I got this error. I don't even know where to start to be able to fix it. Does anyone have idea what could it be?

I am using (amongst others) a package that is installed from my disk, not available on any public source.

Error in if (type == "package") package <- topic : 
  argument is of length zero

I don't expect someone to solve me the problem (if happens I will not complain) but just to point me in a right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Try to disable the packages one-by-one to see which one causes the error.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the error of not being able to run the code

Comment: Found the source of it. Went line by line and saw that I was using a letter from German alphabet that produced a question mark (?) on my new laptop. Thank you anyhow